# JPA: user-defined type is a BasicType?

Tags: jpa, metamodel

Instances of the type BasicType represent basic types (including temporal and enumerated types).

Is a BasicType directly mapping to a database column type?

Can any user-defined type be a BasicType?

```
         Type
  |----------------|
ManagedType    BasicType
```

Is the value(user-defined class) for @IdClass a ManagedType or BasicType?

Answer (score 0):

If a class is not annotated with `@Entity`, `@MappedSuperclass`, `@Embeddable`, then I would expect it to be classified as a "basic" type. That is, at least, how the JPA provider I use does it and it makes sense to me.